# Mocking for MXUnit

Tags: automated-testing, mock

I'm fairly new to Coldfusion; at my new position, we're using MXUnit for unit testing our service library, but so far we're not mocking out the database (so we're testing against live data). I want to introduce better practices for testing the middle layers, but after spending a day playing with MightyMock, the built-in mocking framework for MXUnit 2.x, I found it frustrating and difficult to use as well as limited in features.

Is there a good book or tutorial? Or are people mostly using a third-party library for this? If so, what ones should I investigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our company eventually went with [MockBox](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/MockBox.cfm), which has somewhat better documentation.